# ImageIO.read() failing to read when given a supposedly valid stream

Tags: java

this is probably an obvious error, but I am working with this code:

```
BufferedImage sheet = null;

    try {
        sheet = ImageIO.read(Game.class.getResourceAsStream("spritesheet.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`Game.class.getResourceAsStream("spritesheet.png")` opens the stream correctly, but passing that stream to the read function ends up returning null. Why is this returning null and how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an exception? What's the stack trace?

Comment: There is no exception, just the return value of `null`

Comment: The method is documented to return null in case no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the stream. Is your file really a simple PNG image, or is it using some obscure format? Try with another image, known to really be a png.

Comment: Add a File("spritesheet.png").exists() check.

Comment: usually one uses `getResourceAsStream` to load resources packaged inside the application jar or in the classpath, so `File.exists()` will most likely fail/return false.